# Chrome Lighthouse warning: "Form elements do not have associated labels" (but they do have a label)

Tags: google-chrome, label, lighthouse

I must be missing something obvious - why doesn't this page validate in Google Chrome (Lighthouse) audit?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Label Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">

<label>
<input name="phrase" id="phrase" type="text">
</label>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It says that:

> "Form elements do not have associated labels." Failing elements:

```
<input name="phrase" id="phrase" type="text">
```

(I tried to use `<label for="phrase"` but it still fails.

Comment: The `</label>` needs to go before the `<input>`: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

Answer (score 1):

I think lighthouse is complaining because your label tag doesn't have any content, it is missing the actual label text.

Adjusting the markup to include a description of the form element will allow the page to score 100 for accessibility.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Label Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="form.php" method="post">

      <label>
        field label text
        <input name="phrase" id="phrase" type="text">
      </label>

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

For more information, see the [W3 Web Accessibility Tutorial for labelling controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels).

Comment: What if my form is so simple that doesn't need a label, and I still want to remove the warning?

Comment: If the input doesn't have a label, how will anyone know what to input?

If you want to hide the label, then I would recommend using an [accessible hide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#note-on-hiding-elements), so assistive devices can still understand what it is.

Comment: Yes, there is a case such as, the header of the form described all info, and the input also has a `placeholder` so I removing label makes form cleaner yet understandable... How about this case?

Comment: The placeholder text cannot be relied on to describe the input in the same way as a label can, since it will disappear as soon as the input is focussed [ref](https://webaim.org/articles/label-name/#placeholder). It also won’t be listed in the listing of form labels for the page.

Comment: In your case, the argument that the form doesn’t need a label since it has headings might be ok and I dare say that some users with varying eyesight quality would be able to use it. However in the same way as a page with a green background and yellow text is _technically_ readable, it might not be very nice to use.

Comment: It can be really difficult to imagine all of the different contexts which pages can be consumed, there are so many different kinds of impairments, or combinations of impairments which people can have. This is why we have tools and guidelines which make suggestions to improve our code for users who are using the page in a way we might not have considered.